# WordPress WooCommerce API: Update/insert custom taxonomy terms

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to update a products custom taxonomy term via the wp-json api.

I have added the below function to handle taxonomies:

```
function wp_api_add_tax($post, $data, $update){
    foreach( $data['custom_tax'] as $tax => $val ){
        wp_set_post_terms( $post['ID'], $val, $tax );
    }
}
add_filter('json_insert_post', 'wp_api_add_tax', 10, 3);
```

And then add then taxonomy term like this:

```
$api_response = wp_remote_post( 'https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products/4286', array(
    'headers' => array(
        'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( 'xxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxx' )
    ),
    'body' => array(
            'stock_quantity' => '0',
            'categories' => array(
                array(
                    'id' => 373
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'Build Lean Muscle'
                )
            ),
            'custom_tax' => array(
                'My Taxonomy Here' => 'My Term Here'
            ),

            'meta_data' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'nutritional',
                    'value' => 'nutritional description by the api 2'
                )
            )
        )
) );
```

Is this the correct way of doing things? The custom taxonomy term does not get updated.